# How to completely remove MySQL from my system?

Tags: 20.04, mysql, uninstall

I want to **completely** remove MySQL from my system, including databases, settings, logs, journals, etc.

**How can I do it?**

**Update/Note:** The MySQL was installed using the following terminal commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
OS Mode: Live USB drive with persistent storage
MySQL version: mysql Ver 8.0.20

Comment: How you uninstall/remove something depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1270094/edit) to include that information

Answer (score 18):

As you already know how you installed it and what version you're working with, you can do the following:

Stop the MySQL service:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysqld
```

Purge MySQL, databases, and configurations:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
```

Remove any additional database files:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
```

The folder where the configuration was and any stranglers:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

Clean the logs:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
```

Delete the user-generated during installation:

```
sudo deluser --remove-home mysql
```

Finally, get rid of the usergroup that was created during installation:

```
sudo delgroup mysql
```

That should get rid of everything. If you installed a third-party PPA in order to install MySQL then you'll need to remove that.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:theppayouused/ppa
```

And that *should* be everything related to MySQL and nothing else.

Comment: `sudo delgroup mysql` returns this message `/usr/sbin/delgroup: `mysql' still has `mysql' as their primary group!`

Comment: Check `less /etc/passwd` and see if you have mysql users. If so, you'll need to remove them. Worst case, the existence of the group won't cause any major issues by simply existing.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did, in ubuntu terminal i located mysql by typing in

```bsh
which mysqld
```

For which I got an output

```bsh
/usr/sbin/mysql
```

Further mysql was inside lampp as well, i located it by

```bsh
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -e "select @@socket"
```

For which I got an output

```bsh
/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then i typed in

```bsh
sudo -i
```

and pressed enter to open as root, after which I typed in and removed mysql in one location

```bsh
sudo rm -rf /usr/sbin/mysql
```

Did a restart. and again opened as root in ubuntu terminal and  typed in location of mysql inside lampp

```bsh
sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql
```

Again did a system restart.Next in terminal i typed in

```bsh
mysql
```

I got the output mysql cannot be located, for reassurance purpose I typed in

```bsh
which mysqld
```

No output, mysql has been uninstalled