# Problem with mysql-8.0 when upgrading to 20.04

Tags: server, upgrade, mysql

I'm updating to Ubuntu 20.04, but mysql is hitting problems.  I don't know much, so any help is appreciated.

Here's the output of `apt install mysql-server`:

```
jesse@nietzsche:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2022-04-14T00:25:25.317004Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
insserv: warning: script 'K01cinestart' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K01mythtv-backend' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'S03powernowd.early' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'cinestart' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'powernowd.early' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'mythtv-backend' missing LSB tags and overrides
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-04-13 20:25:41 EDT; 4ms ago
    Process: 137731 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 137754 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 137754 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 2 (No such file or directory)
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Looking in the error log for any clues, I find the following messages during the installation:

```
2022-04-14T00:28:00.489996Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2022-04-14T00:28:00.491037Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 138771
2022-04-14T00:28:00.504296Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2022-04-14T00:28:00.504329Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-04-14T00:28:03.157430Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-04-14T00:28:05.430738Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2022-04-14T00:28:05.430818Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2022-04-14T00:28:10.206763Z 2 [Warning] [MY-010772] [Server] db.opt file not found for test database. Using default Character set.
2022-04-14T00:28:10.211182Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `b`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:28:10.211459Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `a`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:28:11.409430Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2022-04-14T00:28:11.409919Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-14T00:28:12.542597Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2022-04-14T00:28:12.543852Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 138946
2022-04-14T00:28:12.553892Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-04-14T00:28:12.717657Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:13.717906Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:14.718270Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:15.718681Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:16.719077Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:17.719410Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:18.551168Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2022-04-14T00:28:21.291600Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2022-04-14T00:28:21.291652Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2022-04-14T00:28:21.291681Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012216] [InnoDB] Cannot open datafile for read-only: 'mysql.ibd' OS error: 71
mysqld: Can't open file: 'mysql.ibd' (errno: 0 - )
2022-04-14T00:28:26.294781Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-04-14T00:28:26.294952Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-04-14T00:28:26.295256Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-14T00:28:26.295785Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2022-04-14T00:28:26.915032Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2022-04-14T00:28:26.916085Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 139010
2022-04-14T00:28:26.923383Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2022-04-14T00:28:26.923453Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-04-14T00:28:27.347129Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-04-14T00:28:32.286610Z 2 [Warning] [MY-010772] [Server] db.opt file not found for test database. Using default Character set.
2022-04-14T00:28:32.291050Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `b`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:28:32.291362Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `a`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:28:33.363172Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2022-04-14T00:28:33.363565Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-14T00:28:38.646290Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
```

Thereafter, `systemctl status mysql` reports the following:

```
2022-04-14T00:28:00.489996Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2022-04-14T00:28:00.491037Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 138771
2022-04-14T00:28:00.504296Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2022-04-14T00:28:00.504329Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-04-14T00:28:03.157430Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-04-14T00:28:05.430738Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2022-04-14T00:28:05.430818Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2022-04-14T00:28:10.206763Z 2 [Warning] [MY-010772] [Server] db.opt file not found for test database. Using default Character set.
2022-04-14T00:28:10.211182Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `b`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:28:10.211459Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `a`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:28:11.409430Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2022-04-14T00:28:11.409919Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-14T00:28:12.542597Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2022-04-14T00:28:12.543852Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 138946
2022-04-14T00:28:12.553892Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-04-14T00:28:12.717657Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:13.717906Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:14.718270Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:15.718681Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:16.719077Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:17.719410Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-04-14T00:28:18.551168Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2022-04-14T00:28:21.291600Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2022-04-14T00:28:21.291652Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2022-04-14T00:28:21.291681Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012216] [InnoDB] Cannot open datafile for read-only: 'mysql.ibd' OS error: 71
mysqld: Can't open file: 'mysql.ibd' (errno: 0 - )
2022-04-14T00:28:26.294781Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-04-14T00:28:26.294952Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-04-14T00:28:26.295256Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-14T00:28:26.295785Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2022-04-14T00:28:26.915032Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2022-04-14T00:28:26.916085Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 139010
2022-04-14T00:28:26.923383Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2022-04-14T00:28:26.923453Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-04-14T00:28:27.347129Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-04-14T00:28:32.286610Z 2 [Warning] [MY-010772] [Server] db.opt file not found for test database. Using default Character set.
2022-04-14T00:28:32.291050Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `b`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:28:32.291362Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `a`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:28:33.363172Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2022-04-14T00:28:33.363565Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-14T00:28:38.646290Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
```

The error log continues to fill with the following messages:

```
2022-04-14T00:31:30.710096Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2022-04-14T00:31:30.711121Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 140131
2022-04-14T00:31:30.718314Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2022-04-14T00:31:30.718372Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-04-14T00:31:31.944543Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-04-14T00:31:37.218243Z 2 [Warning] [MY-010772] [Server] db.opt file not found for test database. Using default Character set.
2022-04-14T00:31:37.221850Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `b`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:31:37.221965Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `a`" or dump/reload to fix it!
2022-04-14T00:31:38.260933Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2022-04-14T00:31:38.261398Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-14T00:31:43.752969Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
```

I'm totally clueless here.  Aside from mythtv, I have a few databases that I wrote years ago and don't want to lose them somehow, so I'd sure appreciate any advice you can give me.

Comment: "I have a few databases that I wrote years ago and don't want to lose them" ⇠ that is going to bite you. MySQL 8.x is *very* different from previous versions of MySQL and there is a good bit of effort involved with a straight upgrade. It's much easier to simply restore from backup. With that said, if these databases are important, do you have backups available? 

Comment: I'm pleased to say that I have a backup of the only really important database.  I made backups regularly using a cron job.

Comment: If you have a  backup, then remove MySQL from the system [using these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1270107/1222991), then re-install and restore from backup. This is the fastest and safest means available 

Comment: I'd just as soon not lose the myth database which is not, I think, backed up anywhere.  Can I use a USB stick to boot into 18.04, mount the hard drive and then backup the mythtv database?

Comment: I am not the person who can answer your question. This is going to be wholly dependent on your comfort level with "alternative backup methods". There are certainly ways to backup or recover data from older MySQL database files, but it's a long and tedious process. I generally use VMs for this sort of operation 

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I'll see what I can do for the mythtv database before following your directions.  Hopefully I can get to it tomorrow.